# Titanium create custom keyboard module

Tags: titanium, android-softkeyboard, uikeyboard

Is it possible to create something like swiftkeys for Andriod with the Titanium cross-platform development framework? If so, do you know of any examples where this kind of thing has been done before?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible in a sufficient way. Even if you are able to manage top open the app as a partly shown activity (a keyboard should not use all available space ^^) you still have one problem: Titaniums touch gestures are very likely to be delayed. This can be very frustrating in a normal app but a keyboard like SwiftKey would be not usable (typing would still work).

If you are only going to support Android anyway why don't you develop for Android natively?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main objectives of Titanium is to code once and use across different platforms. But in this scenario, I would assume that even-though you would be using titanium, you would have to use custom Native modules, for each OS that you would be working on. I assume that there would not be much room for code-sharing, and I would highly recommend you to go Native for this kind of app.

If you still do insist on using Titanium, you can probably look into modules as such(iOS only): https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1422?restoreSearch=true#!overview